# cordova build error when `node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js` in build phase

Tags: ios, cordova

I am a web developer with no experience in iOS development. Now I'm using Cordova to build iOS app. Because I have no knowledge about iOS or Xcode, it is very hard for me. I always get error like the following output when I built in Xcode or built in command line.

1. Error info in Xcode build:

```
Run custome shell script 'Copy www directory'

PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory /Users/jyjin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myios-auhioanpfinvvvcrnvoaioslreyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myios.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh (in target: myios)
    cd /Users/jyjin/workspace/gitProject/Cordova/FirstProject/platforms/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/jyjin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myios-auhioanpfinvvvcrnvoaioslreyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myios.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh

/Users/jyjin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myios-auhioanpfinvvvcrnvoaioslreyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myios.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh: line 2: 27158 Segmentation fault: 11  node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

2. Error info in command line build:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory /Users/jyjin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myios-auhioanpfinvvvcrnvoaioslreyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myios.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

I have read a lot of solutions on websites, and finally I found that there were some script in build phase:

```
NODEJS_PATH=/usr/local/bin; NVM_NODE_PATH=~/.nvm/versions/node/`nvm version 2>/dev/null`/bin; N_NODE_PATH=`find /usr/local/n/versions/node/* -maxdepth 0 -type d 2>/dev/null | tail -1`/bin; XCODE_NODE_PATH=`xcode-select --print-path`/usr/share/xcs/Node/bin; PATH=$NODEJS_PATH:$NVM_NODE_PATH:$N_NODE_PATH:$XCODE_NODE_PATH:$PATH && node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js
```

after checking out the error message several times, I tried to remove `&& node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js` in **Build Phases**, it builds successfully, but with no page effect expected in html (Cause no www resource copied I think).

and I tried to check out some env PATH value in `copy-www-build-step.js`,so I wrote some log code in `copy-www-build-step.js`, but have no idea how to print js logs in Xcode. Then I found `cordova-plugin-console`, but npm doc said it is duplicated, and contains the last version for Cordova, and mine is also the latest.

Oh, God！One week passed...  I just want to build an iOS app. It’s so hard to play. The ghost knows what I experienced：Configuring certificates, profile, building a Cordova app from scratch, even spending $99 to buy an apple developer account...

Just want to play an iOS app by myself in my free time ... Hope someone can help me ~~

```
     -- From a desperate Chinese boy ！
```

Answer (score 1):

just update `cordova-ios` to latest version:

`npm i cordova-ios@latest`

you can see this problem being solved in this PR: [#600](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/600/files), they changed the script from javascript to the old shell version and fixed the problem.

**Workaround without updating the library**

Enter in xCode in the **Build Phases** tab and click on "Copy www directory" phase, so change the script to:

`$SRCROOT/__PROJECT_NAME__/Scripts/copy-www-build-step.sh`

"__PROJECT_NAME__ " is the name of xCode project.

After this download the [copy-www-build-step.sh](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/project/__PROJECT_NAME__/Scripts/copy-www-build-step.sh) script and put it inside the "__PROJECT_NAME__/Scripts/" path.

**References**

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/540
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/600/files
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/146/files

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I have fixed it~

Firstly, check the script:

```
NODEJS_PATH=/usr/local/bin; NVM_NODE_PATH=~/.nvm/versions/node/`nvm version 2>/dev/null`/bin; N_NODE_PATH=`find /usr/local/n/versions/node/* -maxdepth 0 -type d 2>/dev/null | tail -1`/bin; XCODE_NODE_PATH=`xcode-select --print-path`/usr/share/xcs/Node/bin; PATH=$NODEJS_PATH:$NVM_NODE_PATH:$N_NODE_PATH:$XCODE_NODE_PATH:$PATH && node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js
```

currently error is `xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65`. This is the first error, the `&&` should be `&` when running in the mac.

And then, the error turn to be `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127`.And I found xcode error message: `node: command not found`.

So I run `find /usr/local/n/versions/node/* -maxdepth 0 -type d 2>/dev/null | tail -1` in the command line. and get the node result path `/usr/local/n/versions/node/11.12.0`

run

```
node -v // v10.15.3
```

So I remove all script in build_phases, and give it node path for my real nvm node path, change build_phases like below:

```
/Users/jyjin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js
```

Build success!

Summary! cordova auto build_phases script maybe not suit your environment, make sure build phase can get your node path!